# Converting PEM to PKCS12 using intermediate certificate

Tags: openssl

I'd like to convert a PEM(+key) certificate to a `*.p12` file. I know this is how I do it when I don't have an intermediate certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

How do I do it when I have an intermediate certificate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to concatenate all the PEM files into one, then convert it to PKCS#12:

```
$ cat certificate.crt intermediate.crt > bundle.crt
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in bundle.crt
```